# load CSV file data to snowflake cloud table using batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I new to batch scripting my requirement is to copy CSV file to snowfalke table.

I had try using

> copy into command

provided by SNOWFLAKE documents.

But unfortunately its not working , Please help me with these.

this is what i hand tried yet

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

set fullstamp=select * from Tbl_Store where OperationDate='%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%'
set filename=Tbl_Store_%YYYY%_%MM%_%DD%

sqlcmd -S ta -d SMS_Online  -U sa -P ***-h -1 -s, -W -Q "%fullstamp%" -s "," -o "E:\Workspace\%filename%.csv" 
set File_Name=%filename%.csv
: path to Output the 
set File_PATH=E:\Workspace\

: Set Bucket Path
set AWSBUCKET=s3://S3_TEST

: Set AWS path
set AWSPROFILE= S3_TEST

: upload the ZIP FILE to the AWS
:aws s3 cp %File_PATH%%File_Name% %AWSBUCKET% 

:Copy into SnowFlake
copy into table_name from %File_PATH%%File_Name%
```

Comment: Unfortunately I did not bring my crystal ball with today, so I am unable to see the _"not working"_ code.

Comment: ans is updated  & i think it will  definetly bring your crystal-ball.

Comment: All your code is being executed by CMD.exe. The `COPY` command is a Windows executable and `INTO` is not an option of the `COPY` COMMAND.

Comment: I'm confused, it seems you are mixing batch scripting with Snowflake SQL syntax. I have no idea how this is supposed to work.

Comment: i need to automate process for upload CSV data  to snowflake cloud using batch scripting

Comment: The COPY INTO command is an SQL command, not a windows command so it wont work directly in a shell script like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using the snowsql.exe, which we need to configure.

Through batch i am generating the ddl statement into one text file after that i using below command to execute the SQL statement to execute data load on Snowflake.

```
copy into tablename  from @my_s3_stage/%file_path and name on_error = 'skip_file' force=true;
snowsql -c Schema_Name -f file_path
```

> @my_s3_stage stage need to create on snowfalke IDE